# Rails use of httparty to parse the JSON to external URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

In a Rails application, a user has to be redirected to an external site for external processing.  The controller generates a valid JSON string and a set of headers:

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  "https://some-test.supertester.com/checkout",
  :verify => false, 
  :body => JSON.parse(@payment).to_json,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
    'X-TimeStamp' => "#{Time.now.to_i}",
    'X-API-ID:' => "#{@api_id}",
    'X-API-Signature:' => "#{@api_signature}"
  },
  timeout: 20
)
```

This action is launched by the user via:

```
<%= link_to t('proceed'), data_url_cart_path(id: @existing_cart.id), class: 'button' %>
```

whose controller action generates the above JSON string and call.

However, Rails tries to respond to this action with a view with the same action's name (even generating a blank with `format.json { head :no_content }`), when the goal is to redirect the user to the aforementioned URL with the defined headers and payload.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think the problem is your approach. If you need to send headers to this URL, you can not redirect user to it, since you are not able to send headers when redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTParty` is making a network request with a `json` payload. In this situation `@response` will be the response from the network request. If you call `puts @response.parsed_response.inspect` you will see the `json` returned with said response in the terminal window running your Rails server.

I think you may not need to redirect the user to an external site at all, but instead check the response to see if the action you were trying to make was successful and handle it in your own application.